# Onclick of a button should disable a div in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to disable the div when a button is clicked using angularjs.Onclick of a home button should disable one div of a same page by keeping the remaining div's active.

How can I achieve this? Can anyone please help me out regarding this issue ...

My html code :

```
<button 
    style="margin-left: 22px; margin-top: 16px; background-color: #73AD21" 
    ng-click="getHome()">Home</button>

<div style="margin-top: 15px; display: inline-block" ng-repeat="imageSource in imageSources">
    <img width=40 height=50 style="margin-left: 12px;" ng-src="{{imageSource}}" /> <br> 
    <span style="margin-left: 12px;">{{getFilenameFromPath(imageSource)}}</span>
</div>
```

My js code:

```
$scope.imageSources = [];
$scope.imageSources.push('images/Open.png');
$scope.imageSources.push('images/New.jpg');
$scope.imageSources.push('images/Save.png');

$scope.getFilenameFromPath = function(filename) {
    return filename.split("/")[1].split(".")[0];
}
$scope.getHome = function() {

    window.location = "./Home.html";
}
```

Comment: can you provide the div you want to disable.

Comment: What do you mean by disable div ?

Comment: When I load the page,at the first I need to show  the "MyDiv" div as active.when I click on the home button,I should disable the "MyDiv".

Comment: what is write on div ? is it form ?

Comment: My Div contains set of images which are horizontally aligned.So,I want to disable  those images when I click on home button

Comment: here disabled means hide or not click aur any event fire on ut ?

Comment: Disabled means I don't want to show those images as active.Not clickable

Comment: How can I make all the images in a div as non-clickable(disabled) using angularjs

Comment: please see the answer post i send the solution and also a blog see it. I hope this will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your command, the code should be;

```
<button 
    style="margin-left: 22px; margin-top: 16px; background-color: #73AD21" 
    ng-click="getHome()">Home</button>

<div ng-if="showDiv" style="margin-top: 15px; display: inline-block" ng-repeat="imageSource in imageSources">
    <img width=40 height=50 style="margin-left: 12px;" ng-src="{{imageSource}}" /> <br> 
    <span style="margin-left: 12px;">{{getFilenameFromPath(imageSource)}}</span>
</div>
```

Your js code should be;

```
$scope.showDiv = true;
$scope.imageSources = [];
$scope.imageSources.push('images/Open.png');
$scope.imageSources.push('images/New.jpg');
$scope.imageSources.push('images/Save.png');

$scope.getFilenameFromPath = function(filename) {
return filename.split("/")[1].split(".")[0];
}
$scope.getHome = function() {
    $scope.showDiv = false;
    window.location = "./Home.html";
}
```

Comment: I tried editing by  the code you have suggested.But I'm unable to disable the div.

Comment: when you call getHome you want to hide your div. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: I have edited the answer please, try and let me know is there any problem.

Comment: can u please refer this url : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34611021/how-to-show-hide-a-div-using-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

Write `ng-disabled` in div tag and `ng-click="noClickable()"` with return false;

```
<div ng-disabled="disableDiv" ng-click = "noClickable()">....</div>
```

assign the $scope.disableDiv = true in in the function of controller controller

```
 $scope.noClickable = function(){
         $scope.disableDiv = true;
         return false; 
 }

  $scope.getHome = function() {
        $scope.disableDiv = true;
        window.location = "./Home.html";
    }
```

Please see this link  [Click](http://baudehlo.com/2014/02/24/angular-js-ng-click-still-fires-when-div-is-ngdisabled/)
I hope this will work