# How to show/hide a div using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to hide a div when I click hide button.But I'm unable to show a div if I click on show button.I'm able to do only one action at a time.

If I set "  $scope.showDiv = false;" as default,I'm unable to show the div  even though by using the below code:

```
 $scope.getShow = function() {
            $scope.showDiv = true;
            window.location = "./sample.html";
        }
```

Can anyone please help me out regarding this issue ...

My html code:

```
<div ng-if="showDiv">Hello</div>
<button style="margin-left: 22px; margin-top: 16px; background-color: #73AD21"
ng-click="getShow()">Show</button>
<button style="margin-left: 22px; margin-top: 16px; background-color: #73AD21"
ng-click="getHide()">Hide</button>
```

My js code:

```
$scope.showDiv = false;
$scope.getShow = function() {
        $scope.showDiv = true;
        window.location = "./sample.html";
    }
$scope.getHide = function() {
        $scope.showDiv = false;
        window.location = "./sample.html";
    }
```

I'm trying to access main page from my home page.when I click show button in the home page,it should redirect to main page and show the div.when I click hide button in the home page,it should redirect to main page and hide the div.This is what I'm unable to do currently.

Comment: use ng-show instead of ng-if

Comment: but again why are you trying to redirect using `window.location` inside `getShow` and `getHide` function?

Comment: Why do you have `window.location = "./sample.html";` everywhere? Remove it, and it should work fine.

Comment: Maybe when you navigate with `window.location` you rerun the script and the `$scope.showDiv` is being set to `false` again

Comment: If you change the location, you're telling the browser: delete everything you know about this page, download this new page and restart from scratch. First, you shouldn't use window.location to navigate between views of a single-page angular application. Second: if you do, you actually shutdown the current app, load a new page, which might start a new app. Third, even if you navigate properly, using the angular router, you can't control the visibility of some part of another view. I think you need to read a good angular tutorial, because you don't understand the basic principles of angular.

Comment: Actually I'm beginner to angularjs.

Comment: What should be used instead of "window.location" for redirecting a page.Can u please edit the code here.

Comment: Listen to @JBNizet. This is too big of an error to just get an answer. You should read about angular routing. Also keep in mind that changes in one view (one page) aren't saved for another view. Each page has a separate scope. The `ng-if="showDiv"` actually refers to a `$scope.showDiv` of a different scope. Take a look into the basics of angular scope and angular routing and good luck!

Comment: try removing all of your window.location. Also I think you should use $location instead of window.location.

Answer (score 2):

As people mentioned in comments after you call

```
window.location = "./sample.html";
```

the page might reload and code starting from

```
$scope.showDiv = false;
```

is called again. So you are in cycle when showDiv variable is always false.

What you might want to change is set **if** statement in the beginning

```
if(window.location == "./home")
    $scope.showDiv = true;
if(window.location == "./main")
    $scope.showDiv = false;
```

Comment: In the home page,I don't have that div.I just have a show and hide buttons in home page.In the main page,I have a div.If I click show button in home page,it should show a div in the main page and viceversa.

Comment: So on home page you have hidden div with ng-if="false" and buttons? And on home page ng-if="true" and no buttons? I'm confused now :)

Comment: In home page,I don't have any div,I only  have two buttons.In the main page I have a div,which I need to show in the main page when a show button is clicked from the home page and viceversa

Comment: 2 pages means you have html file for each and you are switching between them using window.location.href , right? or do you have one html?

Comment: Yes.I have two html files and I'm switching between them using window.location